# ValueError: The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint:

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running a deep learning model using the deepxde library [link](https://github.com/lululxvi/deepxde). I am not able to understand what is creating this error? Is it related to any background package like ddepxde, tensorflow or is it realted to some error in my code, where I have incorrectly mentioned the save-path!

Bevause I have checked that the specified path `/Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/ML_project_Spencer/deepOscillations_try-master/models/model/` does exists and I have a folder for it there! How may I solve this problem, shall i ask this problem on deepxde discussion platform?

I am getting the following error while running my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/ML_project_Spencer/deepOscillations_try-master/./main.py", line 310, in <module>
    NN_MSEs_test, NN_MSEs_train = DeepONet(samples, split, y/np.max(np.abs(y)) , I, inds, neurons, epochs, b_layers)
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/ML_project_Spencer/deepOscillations_try-master/./main.py", line 289, in DeepONet
    model.restore( save_dir +save_str+"./model.ckpt-" + str(np.argmin(model.losshistory.loss_test)*100), verbose=0)
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepxde/model.py", line 914, in restore
    self.saver.restore(self.sess, save_path)
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1409, in restore
    raise ValueError("The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint: " +
ValueError: The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint: /Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/ML_project_Spencer/deepOscillations_try-master/models/model/Levin1_Seed_1_Samples_100_X_4_10_epochs_10_blayers_7_neurons_500./model.ckpt-0
```

Where the code of the model which is creating problem is

```
def DeepONet(samples, split, y, I, inds, neurons, epochs, b_layers):
    
import deepxde as dde

net = dde.maps.DeepONet(
    branch,
    trunk,
    "relu",
    "Glorot normal",
    use_bias=True,
    stacked=False,
) #   "relu","Glorot normal",  # batch_size = 


model = dde.Model(data, net)
model.compile("adam", lr=lr, metrics=[mean_squared_error])
checker = dde.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    save_dir+save_str+"./model.ckpt", save_better_only=False, period=100
)
losshistory, train_state = model.train(epochs=epochs, callbacks=[checker]) #Training Model batch_size = 10000
# For plotting the residuals and the training history: isplot=True will plot
dde.saveplot(losshistory, train_state, issave=False, isplot=False)

# Restore the best test loss model
model.restore( save_dir +save_str+"./model.ckpt-" + str(np.argmin(model.losshistory.loss_test)*100), verbose=0)
```

After removing 'dot' from ./model.ckpt as suggested in the comments; we get the following error.

```
Compiling model...
Building DeepONet...
/Users/anshumansinha/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepxde/nn/tensorflow_compat_v1/deeponet.py:187: UserWarning: `tf.layers.dense` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `tf.keras.layers.Dense` instead.
  return tf.layers.dense(
'build' took 0.023814 s

'compile' took 0.084288 s

Warning: epochs is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use iterations instead.
Initializing variables...
2022-09-04 23:39:15.378867: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:354] MLIR V1 optimization pass is not enabled
2022-09-04 23:39:15.380184: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:128] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz
Training model...

Step      Train loss    Test loss     Test metric   
0         [1.67e-01]    [1.58e-01]    [1.58e-01]    
10        [6.67e-03]    [3.39e-02]    [3.39e-02]    

Best model at step 10:
  train loss: 6.67e-03
  test loss: 3.39e-02
  test metric: [3.39e-02]

'train' took 0.054383 s

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/ML_project_Spencer/deepOscillations_try-master/./main.py", line 310, in <module>
    NN_MSEs_test, NN_MSEs_train = DeepONet(samples, split, y/np.max(np.abs(y)) , I, inds, neurons, epochs, b_layers)
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/ML_project_Spencer/deepOscillations_try-master/./main.py", line 289, in DeepONet
    model.restore( save_dir +save_str+"/model.ckpt-" + str(np.argmin(model.losshistory.loss_test)*100), verbose=0)
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepxde/model.py", line 914, in restore
    self.saver.restore(self.sess, save_path)
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1409, in restore
    raise ValueError("The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint: " +
ValueError: The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint: /Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/ML_project_Spencer/deepOscillations_try-master/models/model/Levin1_Seed_1_Samples_100_X_4_5_epochs_10_blayers_3_neurons_125/model.ckpt-100
done1
Using backend: tensorflow.compat.v1

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anshumansinha/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/compat/v2_compat.py:107: disable_resource_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
non-resource variables are not supported in the long term
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anshumansinha/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepxde/nn/initializers.py:118: The name tf.keras.initializers.he_normal is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.keras.initializers.he_normal instead.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What happens if you remove the ```.``` in ```./model.ckpt```?

Comment: @ewong Thanks! The same kind of error comes up! `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/ML_project_Spencer/deepOscillations_try-master/./main.py", line 310, in <module>
    NN_MSEs_test, NN_MSEs_train = DeepONet(samples, split, y/np.max(np.abs(y)) , I, inds, neurons, epochs, b_layers)
  File "/Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/ML_project_Spencer/deepOscillations_try-master/./main.py", line 289, in DeepONet
    model.restore( save_dir +save_str+"/model.ckpt-" + str(np.argmin(model.losshistory.loss_test)*100), verbose=0)`

Comment: Please put the traceback error in your post and not in the comments.

Comment: @ewong sure, done!

Comment: The problem I'm seeing is that you're saving to ```/Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/ML_project_Spencer/deepOscillations_try-master/models/model/Levin1_Seed_1_Samples_100_X_4_5_epochs_10_blayers_3_neurons_125/model.ckpt-100``` which ```Levin..._125``` is a subfolder of the ```model``` folder.  Does the ```Levin..._125``` exist?

Comment: No, not at the moment. Shall, I include that?

Comment: Hi @Formal_that, Try using model.load_weights(checkpoint_path). For more details please refer to this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#checkpoint_callback_options). Thank You.